# Using MATLAB shared library in QT

Tags: matlab, qt

I am going to use a MATLAB shared library in my QT program.

- OS: Ubuntu 15.10
- MATLAB version: MATLAB 2015b
- QT Version: QT 5.5.1

I write a simple MATLAB function.

```
function a = libcalsin(b)
a = b + 4;
end % end of function
```

Then I use MATLAB Library Compiler to generate .so and .h file.

[image: Please see this image]

So the output files are: *libcalsin.so* and *libcalsin.h*. I copy these files to my QT project, and add libcalsin library to my QT project using QT Creator "Add library" feature. So automatically the below lines are added to my .pro file:

```
unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/./ -lcalsin
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/.
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/.
```

In this step, I installed MATLAB 2015 run time engine and add the run time library path, using *export* command:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v90/runtime/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v90/bin/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v90/sys/os/glnxa64:
```

and then add the following line in my .pro file:

```
unix:!macx: LIBS += -L/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v90/runtime/glnxa64/ -lmwmclmcrrt
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v90/extern/include
DEPENDPATH += /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v90/extern/include
```

But when I run my program, I face to the following run time error:

```
An Error has occurred while trying to initialize the MATLAB Runtime.  
The error is: Fatal error loading library /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v90/bin/glnxa64/libmat.so Error: /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v90/bin/glnxa64/libicuio.so.54: undefined symbol: _ZN6icu_5413UnicodeString9doReplaceEiiPKDsii
```

Comment: It appears that you are facing issues with the MATLAB Runtime library. To resolve this issue, you should set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable in your Qt application.